# ReactJs re-use same component but with different styles

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a button component that I wish to re-use in reactJs, I want multiple of the same component to be rendered but using different styles and to use a different style when the button is pressed and also mouse HoverOver

The button component is: -

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
//import './Buttons.css'
const buttons = (props) => {



    return (
      <div className="">

        <button id="buttons" class="-"> {props.name}</button>

        </div>

    );
  }


export default buttons;
```

The main App component holds a state which then the state displays the name of the Button, which I am sure there is a better way of doing this.

Also I have made multiple of a button component and I can apply css styles that way but I am sure this is not the correct way.

```
class App extends Component {



  state = {
    name: [
      { button: 'Login' },
      { buttonTwo: 'Sign Up' },
      { buttons: 'Login' }
    ],

  }
  render() {

    const style = {
      backgroundColor: 'blue',
      font: 'inherit',
      border: '1px solid red',
      padding: '8px',

    };



    var pressed = true
    function toggle() {
      pressed = !pressed

      //When pressed Styles change
    }

    return (
      <div className="App">

       {/* <Right />  Temp Disabled*/}
        <span><Button pressed={pressed} defaultPressed={true} pressedStyle={{color: 'blue'}}
        name={this.state.name[0].button} /></span>
        <span><Button name={this.state.name[1].buttonTwo} /></span>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I eventually aim to create a Log in section so these buttons will be part of that.

Comment: Pass the class as a props to the component

Answer (score 1):

Why not to use just CSS and handle your "mouse HoverOver" and "button is pressed" with native `:active` and `:hover` pseudo-classes? If your styles will be in the CSS, then you can just pass some string as a parameter (e. g. `className`) and simply define necessary styles in the `.css` file

For example

```js
class Application extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="application-wrapper">
        <Button className="red">This is the red button</Button>
        <Button className="blue">This is the blue button</Button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Button extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button className={`my-awesome-button ${this.props.className}`}>{this.props.children}</button>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById("kappa"))
```

```css
.my-awesome-button {
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  border: none;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

.my-awesome-button:hover {
  opacity: .54
}

.my-awesome-button:active {
  opacity: .38
}

.my-awesome-button.red {
  background: red
}

.my-awesome-button.blue {
  background: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="kappa"></div>
```